# Prevented from Rolling Over 401k Due to Company Audit - Legal?

Tags: united-states, 401k, rollover, start-up

A few months back, the startup my wife works for was bought out by a big company.  Everyone was thrilled, of course, and it was a great moment for the whole team.  Soon after the logistics of the buyout were announced, it was made clear that everyone would quit their job at the current company and take a new job at the new company.  That was all done and everyone started their new jobs within a couple weeks of the announcement.

Perfect, I thought!  This is a great opportunity to roll over her 401k to her IRA so we wouldn't be locked in to the limited funds the brokerage offers.  However, a few days after she put in the paperwork for the rollover, the company announced that all rollovers would be on hold until the post-buyout audit was completed.  That *sort of* seemed reasonable, except...

It's been a couple months since then. No timeframe for the audit was announced, nor has one been given in response to her repeatedly asking. I'm a little surprised.  Not to put too fine of a point on it, but is this even legal?  It's our money, not the company's, so it seems awfully questionable.

Comment: I just want to add that the company my wife works for is great, and the new company is excellent.  She has great colleagues and loves the company (new and old alike).  While I'm leaving out the names of both companies deliberately, what's happening here is not typical for her work.

Comment: Is a portion of the 401k unvested?

Comment: Questions about legality should be asked on law.SE. Be that as it may, absent the actual details of what "bought out" means, it may be that the startup's 401(k) plan was _merged_ into the acquiring company's 401(k) plan and there is no opportunity for a rollover at all, and that's what the post-merger audit is revealing.

Comment: you say "it was made clear that everyone would quit their job at the current company and take a new job at the new company. That was all done and everyone started their new jobs within a couple weeks of the announcement" did they actually quit, and was there an actual period of unemployment?  The mergers and splits I have been in have never had a period of unemployment for the regular employees. There were employees who lost their job in the process, but those actions were done before the merger or after the merger.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep No, there was no period of unemployment.  They all got formal offer letters from the new company, signed them, returned them, and started the new jobs several days later.

Comment: @HartCO The old company didn't have any matching contributions, so no, no unvested portion.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Interesting.  How would one figure out if the 401ks are being merged?  The acquisition was a fairly ordinary case of a small startup being acquired by a very large company.

Comment: I worked for a company that was spun out (i.e. separated from parent company, renamed, and listed as new co) then taken private, then bought out by a larger company. None of these 3 events offered an opportunity to take the 401(k) into one's iRA for existing employees.

Comment: @pbarranis Is the 401k custodian a large (well known) firm, or did the 401k statements use the name of a holding company rather than the startup?

Comment: @MorrisonChang The 401k is with John Hancock and the statements say that they're from the company (with address) in the top left, and in the top right they say "The Trustees of {old company here} 401k Retirement Plan".  I'm reading this from a Q3 statement issued days ago even though everyone now works for the new company and has had a new 401k account with the new company for nearly two months.

Comment: @pbarranis Okay so I doubt any 401k custodian shenanigans. It may just be that the big company has a left hand which doesn't know what the right hand is doing. Additional data point, when the startup I was with was bought out, it was the same as your wife, one day old company, next day new company. It did take a while for the 401k to be released (a few months) when I then rolled it over into a IRA. Only suggestion is to check your rights under [ERISA](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/ebsa/about-ebsa/our-activities/resource-center/faqs/retirement-plans-and-erisa-consumer) and ask new company HR.

Comment: I am about 99% sure that the oldcompany 401k plan is NOT being merged into the newcompany plan. It's pretty clear oldcompany and newcompany wanted a clean break. The time this happened to me, existing employees lost any unvested company match, which was sad, but we were able to roll over the balance to an IRA, which was good because the oldcompany 401k was pretty bad. (The newcompany 401k was only slightly better.) Anyways, has your wife pestered HR and/or payroll about this? If so, what did they say? If I were her I would start asking once a week until I got an answer or at least a timeline.

Comment: @stannius I do appreciate the helpful response.  However, an answer to the question would arrive at an authoritative, referenceable source which she could take back to the old company and politely point out that they really need to allow their employees to rollover their money.  Or, if it's what they're doing is allowed, then she'll fall back on polite pestering.

Comment: @pbarranis fair enough, but has your wife asked the payroll, benefits, and/or HR department? And if so what did they say?

Comment: @stannius Yes, a few times.  They say they're performing an audit (or being audited, depending on who's phrasing it) due to the acquisition and rollovers are on hold until the audit is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/100314/what-does-it-mean-if-my-401k-plan-has-been-frozen.asp there is no legal restriction on the length of such a freeze.